# React - Update 2d array in local state without updating every single component in the display grid

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, state

I am using the *VariableSizeGrid* of *react-window* to display a grid.

That grid shows some formatted number and when you click on a cell, you can change the "raw" number (without the formatting) and it gets formatted again when the focus is lost (so onBlur). That part does not seem to work well on CodeSandbox, but it work well on my local app

In my real application, the reportData is retrieved from an api and *delta* is dynamically created (as well as the number of rows, columns, ...) I simplified the code as much as possible to focus on my issue.

I am storing *reportData* and *delta* in the local component state (with UseState). In my real application the reportData is in a redux store, but that is not relevant.

I update the delta in an immutable way using (lodash), but I have one major issue.

Everytime I type a number in an input cell, I can only enter one single digit (and I then lose the focus). So after every digit I enter, the onChange event of *NumberField* is triggered, this one calls the onChange of *Cell*, which call the onChange of *DynamicReport* which then update the state of delta. That state update then triggers a refresh of all Cell (and that's why I cannot type/lose my focus)

I tried adding some debounce, but that did not really solve my issue.

Is using state (so local state) to store my reportData and delta the right approach in my case ?

I have created my example in a CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/input-grid-example-zpotp

Maybe I have a fundamental flaw in my approach, any feed-back/suggestions are welcome

Please find below the code I used for my display component and my report/grid

**number-field.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from "react";

interface NumberFieldProps {
  name: string;
  value: number;
  onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const NumberField = (props: NumberFieldProps): ReactElement => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    props.onChange(event);
  };

  const toFormattedNumber = (number: number) => {
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("de-CH", {
      style: "decimal",
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    });

    return formatter.format(number);
  };

  const toggleEditing = (): void => {
    console.log(
      "NumberFieldDemo toggleEditing called for name: %s",
      props.name
    );
    setIsEditing(!isEditing);
  };

  const generateField = (): ReactElement => {
    if (isEditing) {
      return (
        <input
          type="number"
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          onChange={onChange}
          onBlur={toggleEditing}
          className="inputStd"
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div tabIndex={1} onFocus={toggleEditing}>
          {toFormattedNumber(props.value)}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return <div>{generateField()}</div>;
};

export default NumberField;
```

**report.tsx**

```
// React
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from "react";

// Lodash
import { cloneDeep } from "lodash";
import memoize from "memoize-one";

// react-window
import {
  VariableSizeGrid as Grid,
  GridChildComponentProps
} from "react-window";

// Formatting
import "./report.css";

// Own components
import NumberField from "./number-field";

const ReportDemoState = (): ReactElement => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(400);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);

  const [reportData, setReportData] = useState([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
  ]);
  const [delta, setDelta] = useState([
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ]);

  const Cell = ({
    columnIndex,
    rowIndex,
    style,
    data
  }: GridChildComponentProps): ReactElement => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(
      reportData[rowIndex][columnIndex] + delta[rowIndex][columnIndex]
    );
    const onChange = (
      event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
      rowIndex: number,
      columnIndex: number
    ): void => {
      data.onChange(event, rowIndex, columnIndex);
    };

    const updateValue = (newValue: number) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
      <div className="GridItem" style={style}>
        <NumberField
          name={String(rowIndex) + ":" + String(columnIndex)}
          value={value}
          onChange={(event) => {
            updateValue(Number(event.target.value));
            onChange(event, rowIndex, columnIndex);
          }}
        ></NumberField>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const createItemData = memoize((onChange) => ({
    onChange
  }));

  const DynamicReport = () => {
    const columnWidths = new Array(4).fill(true).map(() => 50);
    const rowHeights = new Array(3).fill(true).map(() => 25);

    const onChange = (
      event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
      rowIndex: number,
      columnIndex: number
    ) => {
      let newDelta = cloneDeep(delta);
      newDelta[rowIndex][columnIndex] =
        Number(event.target.value) - Number(reportData[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
      setDelta(newDelta);
    };

    const itemData = createItemData(onChange);

    return (
      <Grid
        className="Grid"
        columnCount={4}
        columnWidth={(index) => columnWidths[index]}
        height={height}
        rowCount={3}
        rowHeight={(index) => rowHeights[index]}
        width={width}
        itemData={itemData}
      >
        {Cell}
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="full-page">
      <p>Report Demo State</p>
      <DynamicReport />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReportDemoState;
```

**report.css**

```
.Grid {
  border: 1px solid #d9dddd;
}

.GridItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inputStd {
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Please post some of your related code here as well, since the codesandbox link may break in the future, rendering this question useless for future answer-seekers :D

Comment: have added the sample code as requested